# Python - Open Read/Write Error

Tags: python, windows, file, operating-system

I already looked into many answers but none helped me. I need a code that if the file does not exist then create and then open for reading and writing. The code is writing but not reading, what is the problem?

```
>>> `file = open('test.txt', 'w+')`
>>>  file.write('this is a test')
14
>>>  file.read()
''
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to seek to the beginning of the file before attempting to read it.

```
>>> _file = open('test.txt', 'w+')
>>> _file.write('this is a test')
14
>>> _file.read()
''
>>> _file.seek(0)
0
>>> _file.read()
'this is a test'
>>>
```

0 indicates the beginning of the file.
You can get the current position by calling `_file.tell()`
You could programatically combine `_file.tell` with `_file.seek(offset, fromwhat)`.

Also, it is bad practice to use builtin's(file) as variable names.